# I need to write 10 million data from Hbase to a CSV file. What can be used to write the data in a faster rate?

Tags: hbase

Is there any way we can implement writing data in short amount of time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Split it into several jobs that each pull out different parts of the data and write their corresponding csv files (map), then merge the csv files when you're done (reduce).

If you can, run the jobs on different machines, or on one (multi-core) machine and have the output writing to different disks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the data and break it up into different parts using the row keys.
Use the row keys to set the STARTROW and STOPROW properties of your scan.

Now that you have separate scans, you can run them in parallel from different boxes.

Psuedo code:

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\home\you\csvfiles\mycsvfile1.csv");
BufferedWriter wtrBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8"));
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(wtrBuffer, ',');

HTable myTable = null;
try {
      myTable = new HTable(myConfig, "myTable");
} catch (IOException e) {      
  e.printStackTrace();
}

for (Result result : scanner) {
  if (result != null){
  // Just printing the keys because I don't know anything about your data
   writer.writeNext(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()));
}

try {
      myTable.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {        
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

try{

}catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally {   
  System.out.println("Writing to disk...");
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
  stream.flush();
  stream.close();
  System.out.println("Writing to disk...Complete");
}
```

This code uses opencsv: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

Make sure you use a different filename for each scan process.  You can have each process write to a shared folder/network store, or write local then copy to a network store.
When all the processes are done, you can copy all the csv files (mycsvfile1...n.csv) to a single directory if you haven't already.

Then you can merge them into 1 file.

```
copy *.csv all.csv
```

Then open all.csv and you should have your file with 10 million rows.

You could also probably accomplish this using MR with a maponly job that writes to a file in hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple external HIVE table on top of HBASE table and then use the select / export commands on hive to save the data in CSV format.

Step 1:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE mapr_table_1(key int, value string)
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
    > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "/user/mapr/xyz");
```

Step 2: get data into CSV from Hive

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/path/to/hive/csv' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * FROM hivetablename limit 1000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apache drill` to redirect the output to CSV file. Apache drill comes with mapr software.

```
sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:" --outputformat=csv --run=fileWithSQL.sql > Output_CSV_file.csv
```

put your query which reads from habse in `fileWithSQL.sql` file and run the above command.

There are other switches that could be of help in sqlline.